# TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Assuming "color" is a categorical variable:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()

data["color"] = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(data[["color"]])
```

Why is this returning the error:

```
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default return type of `OneHotEncoder.fit_transform()` is a sparse scipy matrix (`scipy.sparse._csr.csr_matrix`).

If the goal is to one-hot encode `color` values and put results back in a dataframe, the `sparse_output=False` parameter is needed (`scikit-learn>=1.2.0`, the previous `sparse` parameter is deprecated).

Such as this:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"color": ["red", "red", "green", "blue"]})

ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)

df[["color1", "color2", "color3"]] = ohe.fit_transform(df[["color"]])
print(df)
```

```
   color  color1  color2  color3
0    red     0.0     0.0     1.0
1    red     0.0     0.0     1.0
2  green     0.0     1.0     0.0
3   blue     1.0     0.0     0.0
```